# Как сжать диаграмму d3.js при помощи Css

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, d3.js

При помощи D3.js Рисую график. Столкнулся с проблемой, пытался адаптировать, страницу к телефоном. и со всеми блоками справился а с графиком  не могу он обрезается но не сжимается. вот код графика.

```js
var width = 850,
    height = 500,
margin=30,
    padding =20,
    data = [
      {"x": 0.3, "label":  1, "value": 51, "selected": 1},
      {"x": 1.3, "label":  2, "value": 67, "selected": 0},
      {"x": 2.3, "label":  3, "value": 74, "selected": 0},
      {"x": 3.3, "label":  4, "value": 63, "selected": 0},
      {"x": 4.3, "label":  5, "value": 56, "selected": 0},
      {"x": 5.3, "label":  6, "value": 24, "selected": 0},
      {"x": 6.3, "label":  7, "value": 26, "selected": 0},
      {"x": 7.3, "label":  8, "value": 19, "selected": 0},
      {"x": 8.3, "label":  9, "value": 42, "selected": 0},
      {"x": 9.3, "label": 10, "value": 88, "selected": 0}

    ];


  var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  // длина оси X= ширина контейнера svg - отступ слева и справа
  var xAxisLength = width - 2 * margin;

  // длина оси Y = высота контейнера svg - отступ сверху и снизу
  var yAxisLength = height - 2 * margin;

  // функция интерполяции значений на ось Х
  var scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, data.length + 1])
    .range([0, xAxisLength]);

  // функция интерполяции значений на ось Y
  var scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([100, 0])
    .range([0, yAxisLength]);

  // создаем ось X
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleX)
    .orient("bottom");

  //  создаем ось Y
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleY)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(4)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d + '%';
    });

  // отрисовка оси Х
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .attr("transform",  // сдвиг оси вниз и вправо
      "translate(" + margin + "," + (height - margin) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  // отрисовка оси Y
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .attr("transform", // сдвиг оси вниз и вправо на margin
      "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")")
    .call(yAxis);

  // выбираем стиль
  d3.selectAll('text')
    .style('font-family', 'Ubuntu');

  // Вертикальные линии
  d3.selectAll("g.x-axis g.tick")
    .append("line") // добавляем линию
    .classed("grid-line", true) // добавляем класс
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", - (height - 2 * margin));

  // рисуем горизонтальные линии
  d3.selectAll("g.y-axis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .classed("grid-line", true)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", xAxisLength)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .attr("stroke","#ff0");

  // создаем объект g для прямоугольников
  var g =svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "body")
    .attr("transform",  // сдвиг объекта вправо
      "translate(" + margin + ", 0 )");
  // связываем данные с прямоугольниками
  g.selectAll("rect.bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar");

  // устанавливаем параметры прямоугольников
  g.selectAll("rect.bar")
    .data(data)
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      return scaleX(d.x);
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return scaleY(d.value) + margin;
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
      return yAxisLength - scaleY(d.value);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d)
    {
      return Math.floor(xAxisLength / data.length) - padding;
    })
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
      if (d.selected === 0) {
        return "#ACBBC2";
      } else {
        return "#EE1D23";
      }
    });

  // кнопка удаления диаграммы
  // onclick= $('.bar').remove();
</script>
```

```css
.axis {      background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    }
    .axis path, .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #333;

    }
    .axis .grid-line {
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispedges;
      font-family: Ubuntu;
      stroke-opacity: 0.2;
    }
    .axis text {
      font: 10px Verdana;
    }

    .bar {
      width : 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот как выглядит на большом экране [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот как на маленьком [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как корректо ее сжать?

Comment: так а размеры холста то меняете? я про width и height, которые стоят первыми в скрипте. Я нигде не увидел операций над расчетами этих величин в зависимости от размеров страниц

Comment: @Mr.Brightside А что вы хотите увидеть. я кинул пример в рабочей  версии это выглядит так media screen and (max-width: 480px) { родительский<div> width 100%, svg width 95% но он не сжался а обрезался. Мне необходимо именно сжатие как картинки.

Comment: У вас в скрипте есть width и height. Какие бы классы CSS вы не применяли к холсту - он останется того размера, который будет скормлен сюда: `d3.select("#chart").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);`. Поэтому он у вас обрезается, а не ужимается. Это можно просто проверить: измените ширину и высоту в скрипте и ваш график изменится. Чтобы ужимать график динамически для разных устройств, вы можете задать media-query для класса элемента, куда встраивается график, а перед запуском построения графика получать ширину/высоту элемента и подставлять в свои height и width

Comment: @Mr.Brightside Пока так и делаю все равно не очень красиво выглядит